# Terminator launching error

Tags: linux, gnome-terminator

When running terminator in shell I get:

```
user@thinkpad:~$ terminator
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 123
    except (KeyError,ValueError), ex:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you change your system's default `python` from `python2` to `python3`?

Comment: wchich version should I use?

Comment: You haven't given us any details of your OS, but on my (Ubuntu) system, `terminator` is a python2 script, with a `/usr/bin/python` shebang. The error you are getting suggests that `/usr/bin/python` resolves to `python3` on your system.